# Family Tree Model in GORM/Grails?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails, grails-2.0

I have problems to model a family tree in GORM/Grails. I know that it is recommended to use a direct acyclic graph to model such a structure.

I started with the Person class:

```
class Persion {
  String name 
}
```

A **Person** can have the following relationships:

- 0 to n children
- 0 to n siblings (these could be sisters or brothers)
- 0 to n partners (these could be wifes or husbands)
- 0 to n parents (thse could be mother or father)

**1. How do I have to model such a relationship structure?**

**2. How do I insert or delete persons from these structure?**

**3. How to guarantee that the resulting graph has no cycles?**

Edit:

Lets assume we have a person A:

- Child relation:

  - If you add child B to A, then child B must get A as a parent.
- Parent relation:

  - If you add parent C to A, then C has a child A
- partner relation:

  - if you add partner D to A, then D has a partner A

Comment: You might also consider this algorithm http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like the following class. It is equivalent for children, parents, etc.

```
class TreeNode  

    {


     String name





     /**
      * This method deletes a node and all the relations that are bound to this node.
      * @return
      */
     def deleteNode() {

      // delete all child relations
      def myChildren = getChildren()
      println "myChildren: "+myChildren*.name

      myChildren.each { child ->
       println "child: "+child.name
       removeFromChildren(child)
      }

      // delete all parent relations
      def myParents = getParents()
      println "myParents: "+myParents*.name
      myParents.each { parent ->
       println "parent: "+parent.name
       removeFromParents(parent)
      }


      delete(flush:true)
     }


     TreeSet<TreeNode> getChildren() {
       TreeNodeChild.executeQuery("select tnc.child from TreeNodeChild tnc where tnc.node = :node", [node: this])
     }


     TreeNode removeFromChildren(TreeNode child) {
      TreeNodeChild.findByNodeAndChild(this, child).delete(flush: true)
      this
     }

     /**
      * Add a node as type (i.e. child) to another node.
      * @param child
      * @return
      */
     TreeNode addToChildren(TreeNode child) {
      TreeNodeChild tnc = new TreeNodeChild(node: this, child: child)
      if (tnc.validate()) {

       if (!isCyclic(child, "type")) {
        println ">>>>>>>> no cycle"
        tnc.save(flush: true)
       }
       else {
        println ">>>>>>>> !!!!!!! cycle found"
       }
      }
      this
     }


     TreeSet<TreeNode> getParents() {
      TreeNodeChild.executeQuery("select tnc.node from TreeNodeChild tnc where tnc.child = :child", [child: this])
     }

     TreeNode removeFromParents(TreeNode parent) {
      TreeNodeChild.findByNodeAndChild(parent, this).delete(flush: true)
      this
     }

     TreeNode addToParents(TreeNode parent) {
      TreeNodeChild tnc = new TreeNodeChild(node: parent, child: this)
      if (tnc.validate()) {

       if (!parent.isCyclic(this, "type")) {
        println ">>>>>>>> no cycle"
        tnc.save(flush: true)
       }
       else {
        println ">>>>>>>> !!!!!!! cycle found"
       }
      }
      this
     }







     private boolean isCyclic(node) {
      boolean cyclic = false
      def myParents = this.getParents()

      // if there are parents of this node
      if (myParents.size() != 0) {

       // if the new node is in the parents set of this node
       if (myParents.contains(node)) {
        cyclic = true
        return cyclic
       }
       else {
        // go into each parent of this node and test if new node is contained in their parents
        myParents.each { parent ->
         if (cyclic) {
          return cyclic
         }
         cyclic = parent.isCyclic(node)
        }
       }
      }

      return cyclic
     }





    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The toughest part will be to make sure there isn't any recursion. The easiest way I can think of to model it would be:

```
class Persion {
  Person mother
  Person father
  String name 

  //The methods for the other collections would be the same
  Set<Person> getChildren() {
    PersonChild.executeQuery("select pc.child from PersonChild pc where pc.person = :person", [person: this])
  }

  Person removeFromChildren(Person child) {
      PersonChild.findByPersonAndChild(this, child).delete()
      this
  }

  Person addToChildren(Person child) {
    //Something like this to prevent recursion
    //Save should fail if the person already has that person as a child

    List<Person> others = [mother, father]
    others += siblings
    others += partners

    PersonChild pc = new PersonChild(person: this, child: child)
    if (pc.validate()) {
      if (!others.contains(child)) {
        pc.save()
      }  
    }
    this
  }
}

class PersionChild {
  Person person
  Person child
}

class PersionSibling {
  Person person
  Person sibling
}

class PersonPartner {
  Person person
  Person partner
}
```

You can model the Person* tables after the default UserRole table that the Spring Security plugin creates.

Comment: Is this an efficient implementation? I mean what I you want to query the Person relations

Comment: I don't understand your question: "I mean what I you want to query the Person relations". If you can think of a more efficient way, let me know.

Comment: How can you be sure that there are no cycles in the graph? Can you explain your code a bit more what does List<Person> others = [mother, father] do? How would you do delete? When you add a child you have to ensure that in the child person has a father or a mother. How would you do that?

Comment: I think it will be simpler to use parents instead of father and mother!

Comment: Mother and Father are nullable false by default so a person could not be created without both. I'll add a delete method - see edit. `List<Person> others = [mother, father]` creates a List that contains the mother and father.

Comment: could you please update your answer that you use only parent instead of father and mother?

Comment: No I can't. stackoverflow isnt for providing complete code. Figure it out

Comment: I did not understand how you model the parent relationship. Can you give me a hint for that and how I can delete it?

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with GORM/Grails. Research suggests it is essentially Java.

This is the kind of structure I would use in a plain Java environment.

A `Person` object that holds all relationships and some simple utility methods (such as your `getSiblings` which traverses the children of all parents).

The relationships would be managed as `Set`s to reduce the amount of referential integrity checking you must do (but it won't eliminate it).

The relationships will be created and destroyed using factory methods. I have used an `enum` in my sample.

I have not implemented getters and setters for brevity. Your final solution should use them properly.

I have not attempted any of the subtler mechanisms you are likely to need - such as adding a child to a specific pair of parents. This would be achievable but unnecessarily complex in this context.

```
public class Person {
  // Using HashSet to limit possibilities of cycles - we can assume no person exists twice in each.
  private final Set<Person> parents = new HashSet<>();
  private final Set<Person> partners = new HashSet<>();
  private final Set<Person> children = new HashSet<>();
  // Person details.
  private final String name;

  // Constructor.
  public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  // Extract all siblings as all children of all parents.
  public Set<Person> getSiblings() {
    Set<Person> siblings = new HashSet<>();
    for (Person parent : parents) {
      siblings.addAll(parent.children);
    }
    return siblings;
  }

}

// A factory to handle family connections.
public enum Connection {
  ParentOf {
            @Override
            void connect(Person a, Person b) {
              // Connect through a's children and b's parents.
              connect(a.children, b, b.parents, a);
            }

            @Override
            void disconnect(Person a, Person b) {
              // Connect through a's children and b's parents.
              disconnect(a.children, b, b.parents, a);
            }

          },
  PartnerOf {
            @Override
            void connect(Person a, Person b) {
              // Connect through a's children and b's parents.
              connect(a.partners, b, b.partners, a);
            }

            @Override
            void disconnect(Person a, Person b) {
              // Connect through a's children and b's parents.
              disconnect(a.partners, b, b.partners, a);
            }

          },
  ChildOf {
            @Override
            void connect(Person a, Person b) {
              // The opposit of parent.
              ParentOf.connect(b, a);
            }

            @Override
            void disconnect(Person a, Person b) {
              // The opposit of parent.
              ParentOf.disconnect(b, a);
            }

          };

  abstract void disconnect(Person a, Person b);

  abstract void connect(Person a, Person b);

  /**
   * Connect b to a through aSet and a to b through bSet
   *
   * @param aSet The set in person a
   * @param b The b person
   * @param bSet The set in person b
   * @param a The a person
   */
  void connect(Set<Person> aSet, Person b, Set<Person> bSet, Person a) {
    aSet.add(b);
    bSet.add(a);
  }

  /**
   * Reverse of connect.
   *
   * @param aSet The set in person a
   * @param b The b person
   * @param bSet The set in person b
   * @param a The a person
   */
  void disconnect(Set<Person> aSet, Person b, Set<Person> bSet, Person a) {
    aSet.remove(b);
    bSet.remove(a);
  }

}

public class Tree {
  // Safe version - ensuring relationships are maintained.
  public void connect(Person a, Connection c, Person b) {
    c.connect(a, b);
  }

  public void test() {
    Person adam = new Person("Adam");
    Person eve = new Person("Eve");
    Person cain = new Person("Cain");
    Person abel = new Person("Abel");
    connect(adam, Connection.PartnerOf, eve);
    connect(adam, Connection.ParentOf, cain);
    connect(eve, Connection.ParentOf, cain);
    connect(adam, Connection.ParentOf, abel);
    connect(eve, Connection.ParentOf, abel);
  }

}
```

The final part of your question:

> 1. How to guarantee that the resulting graph has no cycles?

Actually - without some huge effort - you can't! I suspect it is impossible but also remember that there can be cycles in a real family tree. It is quite common for users to accidentally create cycles. It is also common to descend from the same ancestor in more than one way - all it takes is a cousin marriage and those are perfectly legal.

This should not be a requirement of your structure, it should be a discoverable feature of your structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that I did for your question

**Domain classes**

```
class Children {
String childrenName
static belongsTo = [person:Person]  
}
class Parent {
String parentName
static belongsTo = [person:Person]
}
class Partner {
String partnerName
static belongsTo = [person:Person]
}
class Person {
String personName
static hasMany = [childrens: Children,
                    parents: Parent,
                    partners: Partner,
                    siblings: Sibiling]
}
class Sibiling {
 String sibilingName
static belongsTo = [person:Person]
}
```

Then in the controller **I am violating the stdandard rules do this in services**

```
def person = new Person();
person.personName = "Suganthan"
def children = new Children()
children.childrenName = "SuganthanchilName"
def parent = new Parent()
parent.parentName = "SuganthanParentName"
def partner = new Partner()
partner.partnerName = "SuganthanPartnerName"
def sibling = new Sibiling()
sibling.sibilingName = "SuganthanSibiligsName"

person.addToChildrens(children)
person.addToParents(parent)
person.addToPartners(partner)
person.addToSiblings(sibling)
person.save()
```

**And then again in service to get the required result**

```
def criteria = Children.createCriteria();
Children children = criteria.get {
eq('id',1 as long)
}

def criteria1 = Parent.createCriteria();
Parent parent = criteria1.get {
eq('id',1 as long)
}

def criteria2 = Partner.createCriteria();
Partner partner = criteria2.get {
eq('id',1 as long)
}

def criteria3 = Sibiling.createCriteria();
Sibiling sibiling = criteria3.get {
eq('id',1 as long)
}

    println(children.person.personName)
    println(parent.person.personName)
    println(partner.person.personName)
    println(sibiling.person.personName)
```

**My result is**

Suganthan

Suganthan

Suganthan

Suganthan

Hope this is what your are expecting and helps a lot